# How do I convert HAL JSON data into JSON array for jQuery DataTables

Tags: json, datatables, laminas-api-tools

I need output data in JSON array format to use with jQuery DataTables but my API from Apigility gives HAL+JSON. How can I convert it so that I can pass it from fetchAll method of API to AJAX URL of Datatables?

Here is what the HAL+JSON looks like:

```
{"_links":{"self":{"href":"http:\/\/parekh.com\/exportmanager\/courses"}},"_embedded":{"courses":[{"Module Title":"Preventing Harassment","Module ID":"HUR602","Module Language":"English"},{"Module Title":"Conflict","Module ID":"COM236","Module Language":"Dutch"},{"Module Title":"Workplace","Module ID":"HUR711","Module Language":"Dutch"}]},"total_items":3}
```

Comment: Is this of any use? [https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/27383/supporting-hateoas](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/27383/supporting-hateoas)

Comment: Hey Thanks,but this doesn't solve it.The datatable is not accepting HAL+JSON format using this method.Any suggestions to convert?

Comment: What does the json look like?

Comment: @markpsmith Added the json output.How do I use this in Datatables?

Comment: I somehow need to pass the _embedded part to the dataTable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

No need to convert the format of the data, jQuery DataTables is able to read complex structures when correct options are used.

Use [`ajax.dataSrc`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option to define data source for the table and [`columns.data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) option to set data source for each column.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/3ebaq',
        dataSrc: '_embedded.courses'
    },
    columns: [
        { data: 'Module Title' },
        { data: 'Module ID' },
        { data: 'Module Language' }
    ]
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3vtL5yb/) for code and demonstration.